# Using strategy design pattern with an abstract parameter

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles, strategy-pattern

I am currently working on a pretty simple project to improve my SOLID and Design Patterns Knowledge.
The idea was to create a "Smart Lock" for a door that can recognize a person by different parameters such as fingerprints, facial recognition, etc.

I immediately saw the potential in using the Strategy Design Pattern, and therefore I created a **Lock** interface and a **Key** abstract class:

```
public interface Lock {
    boolean unlock(Key key);
}

public abstract class Key {
    private String id;

    public String getId(){
        return (this.id);
    }
}
```

I created two classes that will extend **Key** - **FacePhoto** and **FingerPrint**:

```
public class FacePhoto extends Key {
}

public class FingerPrint extends Key {
}
```

Then I created classes that implement **Lock** such as **FingerPrintRecognizer** and **FacialRecognizer**:

```
public class FacialRecognizer implements Lock {
    @Override
    public boolean unlock(Key key) throws Exception {
        if(key instanceof FacePhoto){
            //check validity
            return true;
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("This key does not fit this lock");
        }
    }
}

public class FingerPrintRecognizer implements Lock {
    @Override
    public boolean unlock(Key key) throws Exception {
        if(key instanceof FingerPrint){
            //check validity
            return true;
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("This key does not fit this lock");
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't really find a better way to handle cases in which users of the **Lock** interface will try to open Locks with keys that don't fit.
Also, I had trouble with the "instanceof" if statement because it appears in every class that implements **Lock**.

Is Strategy a good practice in this case? if not, what would be a fine alternative (a different Design Pattern perhaps).

Comment: You shouldn't use `instanceof` to diferentiate between keys, your `Key` interface should have the necessary abstractions for any client and each class that implements it will have its own version of the methods. 

For the other part of your question there are alternatives. You could pass the Key to the Locks as a dependency and use a factory to create the Lock that matches the Key. Or Maybe switch to a Command pattern where each implementation contains a matching Key and the unlock logic. There are probably more solutions

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
When you said: "your Key interface should have the necessary abstractions for any client and each class that implements it will have its own version of the methods"
What do you mean by "the necessary abstractions"? how will this help identifying a key?
Moreover, when you said: "You could pass the Key to the Locks as a dependency and use a factory to create the Lock that matches the Key. "
If you assume that every lock has one key, then maybe it's a good idea. But a lock can have many keys to open it (many different fingerprints).

Comment: 1) What does the Lock need to verify a Key? Is that something that all Key implementations share? Your Key abstraction contains only an id, but that's clearly not enough for a validity check since you need to verify the concrete class of the Key on the Lock.
2) You would have some factory that takes, say, one Key if you need a single Key Lock or another that takes a List of Keys if the Lock consumes multiple Keys. But they would all be Key implementations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strategy pattern provides the ability to change behavior at runtime. In your case a particular concrete implementation of Lock can work with specific implementation of key and thereby the logic does not allow the behavior change so the pattern is a misfit in current implementation.

Example for Strategy  pattern.

```
 class A{
    private Behavior b; //behavior which is free to change
    public void modifyBehavior(Behavior b){
         this.b = b;
    }
    public  void behave(){
          b.behave(); // there is no constraint of a specific implementation but any implementation of Behavior is allowed.
     }
 }

 class BX implements Behavior {
     public void behave(){
           //BX behavior
     }
 }

 class BY implements Behavior {
     public void behave(){
           //BY behavior
     }
 }

interface Behavior {
      void behave();
}
```

In your case you need to refactor the abstractions to better fit the logic.

As a refactoring (not using strategy pattern for current situation as forcing design pattern usuage is a bad practice, currently **L** from **SOLID** principles is being violated ) you can consider another answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49763677/504133

Comment: Thanks! How would you suggest to refactor the abstractions?

Comment: Class that accepts an abstraction must allow any implementation, In your case like FacialRecognizer accepts an abstraction so abstraction should be such that whose all the implementations are allowed for FacialRecognizer, hence You may have abstract FacePhoto and can have multiple implementations. Though it depends on your use case if there are just different objects but single implementation of FacePhoto then you may consider not using strategy pattern as behavior change at run time is not required for current case.

Comment: Forcing a design pattern is not good. When situation demands for one then only we should apply them. Usually following principles lead to one of the design pattern. In your implementation you violate *L* in SOLID

Answer (score 3):

A `Lock` can be opened using a specific type of `Key`

```
interface Lock<K extends Key> {
    void unlockUsing(K key);
}

interface Key {
    // TODO
}
```

A `Door` is composed of multiple `Lock` objects. Each `Lock` may require a different type of key. But you want to keep the interface "single-entry".

```
class Door {
    private Lock<FacePhoto> faceLock;
    private Lock<FingerPrint> printLock;

    public void unlockUsing(Key key) {
        // which lock to use?
    }
}
```

**We need some way to dispatch the key to the correct lock.** If a `FacePhoto` is used for the `Key`, we want the `faceLock` to be used.

Currently, the `Key` is the only one who knows/decides which lock should be used. **Why not allow the `Key` to decide which lock to use?**

First, for the key to decide which lock to use, we need to somehow pass these locks to the key. We can hide the different locks behind a facade and pass that to `Key`:

```
class Door {
    private LockSet locks;

    public void unlockUsing(Key key) {
        key.unlock(locks); // the key will decide!
    }
}

interface Key {
    void unlock(LockSet locks);
}

class LockSet {
    private Lock<FacePhoto> faceLock;
    private Lock<FingerPrint> printLock;

    public void unlockUsing(FacePhoto photo) {
        faceLock.unlockUsing(photo);
    }

    public void unlockUsing(FingerPrint print) {
        printLock.unlockUsing(print);
    }
}
```

Now to implement your keys:

```
class FacePhoto implements Key {
    public void unlock(LockSet locks) {
        locks.unlockUsing(this);
    }

    public boolean matches(FacePhoto photo) {
        boolean matches = false;
        // TODO: check if match
        return matches;
    }
}

class FingerPrint implements Key {
    public void unlock(LockSet locks) {
        locks.unlockUsing(this);
    }

    public boolean matches(FingerPrint print) {
        // TODO: check if match
    }
}
```

**You can't use the wrong key with the wrong lock.** All the potential locks are specified via `LockSet`. Since `LockSet` exposes a type-safe interface, you cannot try to open a `Lock<FacePhoto>` with a `FingerPrint`, the compiler won't let you (which is a good thing - catch mismatch errors before runtime). You cannot try to use unsupported keys either.

This design is called the [visitor pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). If there's something you disagree with, or need further explanation, please let me know.

Comment: Impressive usuage of visitor pattern but now LockSet needs to know about all the implementations of Key and Lock, but anyways it's a trade-off which is there and should be acceptable. Only if you could help mentioning about the OP's concern about usuage of strategy pattern in current situation. Plus one for visitor pattern usuage I have included link to your answer in mine.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the Strategy Pattern is good when the relationship between two abstractions is one-to-many. For example, if you have one lock and many keys that can be used to open the lock. For example, the following would be a good case for the Strategy Pattern:

```
public class Lock {

     public void unlock(Key key) {
         // Unlock lock if possible
     }
}

public interface Key {
    public int someState();
}

public class FooKey implements Key {

    @Override
    public int someState() { ... }
}

public class BarKey implements Key {

    @Override
    public int someState() { ... }
}
```

What you have in your question is a many-to-many problem, with many locks that can be opened by a multiplicity of keys, where some keys can be used to open some locks and cannot open others. For this type of problem, the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is a good choice, where the algorithm is the unlocking process and the object is the lock. The benefit of this approach is that the success or failure lock (whether a specific key unlocks a specific lock) is contained in simple methods without using `instanceof`.

In general, using `instanceof` signifies that some form of polymorphism is needed (i.e. instead of testing each supplied object to see if it is a certain type and executing logic based on that type, the type should have a polymorphic method whose behavior varies depending on the object type). This issue is so common, there is a standard refactoring to replace it: [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism).

To implement the Visitor Pattern for your purposes, you can try something akin to the following:

```
public class UnlockFailedException extends Exception {

    public UnlockFailedException(Lock lock, Key key) {
        this("Key " + key.getClass().getSimpleName() + " failed to unlock lock " + lock.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    public UnlockFailedException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

public interface  Lock {
    public void unlock(Key key);
}

public interface Key {
    public void unlock(FacialRecognizer lock) throws UnlockFailedException;
    public void unlock(FingerPrintRecognizer lock) throws UnlockFailedException;
}

public class FacialRecognizer implements Lock {

    @Override
    public void unlock(Key key) {
        key.unlock(this);
    }
}

public class FingerPrintRecognizer implements Lock {

    @Override
    public void unlock(Key key) {
        key.unlock(this);
    }
}

public class FacePhoto extends Key {

    @Override
    public void unlock(FacialRecognizer lock) throws UnlockFailedException {
        // Unlock the lock
    }

    @Override
    public void unlock(FingerPrintRecognizer lock) throws UnlockFailedException {
        throw new UnlockFailedException(lock, this);
    }
}

public class FingerPrint extends Key {

    @Override
    public void unlock(FacialRecognizer lock) throws UnlockFailedException {
        throw new UnlockFailedException(lock, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void unlock(FingerPrintRecognizer lock) throws UnlockFailedException {
        // Unlock the lock
    }
}
```

It may be tempting to group the `unlock` logic for each `Lock` into an abstract class (since it the same for every `Lock` implementation), but this would break the pattern. By passing `this` to the supplied `Key`, the compiler knows which overloaded method to call. This process is called [double-dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch). Although it may appear tedious, the logic of the call is simple (one line) and therefore, although there is repetition, it is not severe.

The drawback to this approach is that the `Key` interface must have an `unlock` method for each *implementation* of `Lock`. If one is lacking, the compiler will complain when the `Lock` implementation is made, since its `unlock` method will call `unlock` on `Key`, which does not contain a method that accepts the new `Lock` implementation. In that sense, the compiler acts as a check that ensures that a `Key` implementation can handle (either unlock or fail to unlock) each `Lock` implementation.

You can also implement a `KeyRing` that holds many `Key` objects can unlock a `Lock` using each of the `Key` objects until one is found that opens the `Lock`. If no `Key` is on the `KeyRing` that can open the `Lock`, a `UnlockFailedException`:

```
public class KeyRing {

    public final List<Key> keys = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addKey(Key key) {
        keys.add(key);
    }

    public void removeKey(Key key) {
        keys.remove(key);
    }

    public void unlock(Lock lock) throws UnlockFailedException {

        for (Key key: keys) {
            boolean unlockSucceeded = unlockWithKey(lock, key);
            if (unlockSucceeded) return;
        }

        throw new UnlockFailedException("Could not open lock " + lock.getClass().getSimpleName() + " with key ring");
    }

    private boolean unlockWithKey(Lock lock, Key key) {
        try {
            lock.unlock(key);
            return true;
        }
        catch (UnlockFailedException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

If the `UnlockFailedException` is too obtrusive, the `unlock` methods of `Key` can be changed to return a `boolean` that denotes if the unlock process succeeded. For example:

```
public interface Key {
    public boolean unlock(FacialRecognizer lock);
    public boolean unlock(FingerPrintRecognizer lock);
}

public class FacePhoto extends Key {

    @Override
    public boolean unlock(FacialRecognizer lock) {
        // Unlock the lock
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean unlock(FingerPrintRecognizer lock) {
        return false;
    }
}

public class FingerPrint extends Key {

    @Override
    public void unlock(FacialRecognizer lock) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void unlock(FingerPrintRecognizer lock) {
        // Unlock the lock
        return true;
    }
}
```

Using `boolean` return values also simplifies the implementation of the `KeyRing`:

```
public class KeyRing {

    public final List<Key> keys = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addKey(Key key) {
        keys.add(key);
    }

    public void removeKey(Key key) {
        keys.remove(key);
    }

    public boolean unlock(Lock lock) throws UnlockFailedException {

        for (Key key: keys) {
            boolean unlockSucceeded = lock.unlock(key);
            if (unlockSucceeded) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```